# How do i send a .bmp file using socket apis in c at one go?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, tcp

I have a file pict.bmp which i need to send over the LAN.There is a server which starts listening on a port.After the client establishes connection with the server,it requests the server providing a file name for the file.The server then uses the filename and sends to the client.But the problem is that the server sends it successfully using the sendfile() system call but the file does not appear in the directory in which the client is running.is there a better way to do it i.e some other system call which fulfills the same purpose.I am copy pasting the sending a receiving part here :

server :

```
 while(1){

                    nsd = accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&clit,&clen);

                    if(nsd < 0){

                            eMsg("Accept error");

                    }

                    rc = recv(nsd, filename, sizeof(filename), 0);

                    if (rc < 0) {

                            eMsg("Receive error");

                    }

                    printf("Filename : %s\n",filename);

                    filename[strlen(filename) - 1] = '\0';

                    if (strcmp(filename, "quit") == 0) {

                            fprintf(stderr, "quit command received, shutting down server\n");

                            break;
                    }

                    fd = open("2bird.bmp", O_RDONLY);

                    printf("fd is %d\n",fd);

                    if (fd < 0) {

                            eMsg("File Open error");

                    }

                    offset = 0;

                    rc = sendfile (nsd, fd, NULL, 1);

                    if (rc < 0) {

                        eMsg("File Send error");

                        fprintf(stderr,"Sending failed");

                }

                if (rc != stat_buf.st_size) {

                        eMsg("File Transfer error");

                }

                close(fd);

                close(nsd);
```

client :

```
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     39
     40         serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     41
     42         bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
     43
     44         serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
     45
     46         if (connect(sd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
     47
     48                 eMsg("Connection error");
     49
     50         }
     51
     52         printf("Please enter the filename : ");
     53
     54         bzero(buffer,256);
     55
     56         fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
     57
     58         n = write(sd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
     59
     60         if (n < 0)
     61
     62         error("Writing To Socket error");
     63
     64
     65         close(sd);
     66
     67         return 0;
     68
     69 }
     70
     71 void eMsg(char *M){
     72
     73         perror(M);
```

Comment: Please let me know as to what should the client program have been like for the same ?

Comment: If it's the client part that's failing, then yes, please post the relevant part from that. Please try and improve the formatting too, if you can, the indentation is all strange in what you posted.

Comment: Line numbers make it worse. Where's the code where you save to a file on the client side?

Comment: `filename[strlen(filename) - 1] = '\0';` is dangerous. strlen() could be zero. Also: the filename need not be nul-terminated. The client sends strlen(buffer), which is the length **without the NUL** (but it does include a '\n' which is not a NUL)

Comment: @Mat : That is what i do not know how to implement.I was thinking of using something like recvfile() on the client side but found that not many around use that system call.Could you suggest an alternate way?

Comment: @wildplasser : Okay let me try doing that.But this part works fine anyway.My question is how to receive the big file at one go.Is there something equivalent to sendfile() which would enable me to receive a file on the client side.I was trying to play around with recvfile() but could not find enough examples on the web.

Comment: The underlying problem is that you are assuming message boundaries in the TCP stream. There are no message boundaries. Deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, on server you have called sendfile() which copies data from fd(file descriptor for bmp file) to nsd(the socket). So you have copied file content to the socket descriptor. But to fetch this content at client you have to receive data from this socket at the client side.

Since you are not doing this, that's why you are not getting file at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Insert e. g.

```
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
    int fd = open(buffer, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0666);
    while (n = read(sd, buffer, 256), n > 0) write(fd, buffer, n);
    close(fd);
```

before

```
    close(sd);
```

(error checks to be added). Surely, buffer sizes of higher orders would be more efficient.